# Jenkins stage Docker OCI runtime failure

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using a Jenkinsfile to build an application and deploy via Ansible while using a Docker image for its build agent within the Jenkinsfile.  Upon a safe restart of Jenkins, I am now seeing my Jenkins jobs failing for the following error that previously never appeared. Nothing has changed in the Jenkinsfile or in the configuration and there is no config.json in the project I am building so I am unsure where this is arising from.

```
Running shell script
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting 
container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/opt/software/jenkins/workspace/Engineering-develop@3\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory": unknown
process apparently never started in /opt/software/jenkins/workspace/Engineering-develop@3/durable-38313533
```

Comment: i see this sporadically as well in jenkins builds using the kubernetes-plugin, did u ever get any more information on this?